# np.clip vs np.max to limit lower value

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Let's say I am trying to codify `max(0, x)` (the formula for [ReLU activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks))) with numpy, where `x` is a numpy array.

I can think of two obvious implementations:

- `np.clip(x, a_min=0, a_max=None)`
- `numpy.maximum(0, x)`

Which is the better choice, and why?

Comment: Time the difference between the two. And think about which one you find easier to read / to convey the intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific application, [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) should be more efficient (you only need one of the tests performed by `clip`):

```
# setting up random example
a = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=1_000_000)

%%timeit
np.maximum(0, x)
9.62 µs ± 833 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%%timeit
np.clip(x, a_min=0, a_max=None)
52.5 µs ± 9.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```